# Using init_printing to print multiple Matrices in a in Jupyter notebook cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I have two matrices that want to print in one jupyter cell using init_printing, When I try printing them both only the last one gets printed.

```
import numpy as np 
from sympy import init_printing, Matrix

L = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0], [-1, 0.5, -1]])
b = np.array([2, 4, 2])

Matrix(L)
Matrix(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's how jupyter-notebook cells work, only the last returned output will be shown. If you want both, do:

### solution 01

```
Matrix(L), Matrix(b)
```

Output:

[image]

### solution 02

Now, if you do insist to print one after another in the next line, you can use the `display` module like this:

```
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np 
from sympy import Matrix

L = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0], [-1, 0.5, -1]])
b = np.array([2, 4, 2])

display(Matrix(L))
display(Matrix(b))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there any other way to print them below each other without parentheses  or comma?

Comment: well, you can use display module. I am adding that answer too.